# can't wake up after suspension

Tags: 14.04, suspend, intel-graphics, thinkpad

I suspended Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad T400 last night, but this morning when I tried to wake it up, I heard a little sound which is normal when it wakes up, and  then the screen keeps black as if it were still in suspension, but the system is still powered on instead of sleeping indicated by the state indicator lights.

The not waking up problem doesn't happen often. most of time it works fine.

1. I saw some posts pointing to the problem of NVidia video cards.  I
   am using [Intel GMA X4500HD (IGP) max.384MB shared memory](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_GMA_4500MHD), which
   `lshw` calls "Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics
   Controller" with "driver=i915".  Is mine a NVidia video card? Shall I install some
   driver for mine (I didn't install video card driver specially, and
   has 14.04 by default already installed one?)
2. I was running lots of  software programs (including firefox with ~300 tabs, and a virtual machine in
   VirtualBox where I run some pdf editing software). But I have 8GB RAM and 16GB swap, and I didn't notice
   any slowing down (which is normal during heavy swapping) before I
   suspended my system. So I am not sure if the not waking problem is
   because my swap is too small.
3. Can it be because the brightness of my screen is changed to be very dark after waking up, and I was mislead to think the waking failed? (I think unlikely, because normally at the darkest level, I can still see my screen)
4. Besides video cards, what else may cause  not waking from
   suspension?

Thanks.

Comment: it happens to me also, in my case the brightness of my screen changed to very dark, so I can't see it.